# Urls not redirecting in django

Tags: django, redirect, django-admin

I wanted to redirect some urls in my django project.
So i tried using django redirects app.

**In settings.py** :-

```
SITE_ID=1

INSTALLED APPS = (
     ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

I did syncdb  and then added the redirect from admin. Nothing happens.
Is there anything i missed?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? What are the values of your redirects?

Comment: So suppose if i wanted to redirect /section/page1/ to /section/page2/, page1 is not being redirected to page2.

Comment: how are you trying for?